# How to make user make a like action in facebook ? what is the OBJECT_ID to add to the requestWithGraphPath?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium

In my app there is a label which once clicked should make the user making a 'like' action on facebook.
[In this question](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/164106/how-to-make-user-make-a-like-action-in-facebook--what-is-the-objectid-to-add-to-the-requestwithgraphpath-) there is the following piece of code supposed to make that action :

```
// Change OBJECT_ID to an actual object id
    Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('OBJECT_ID/likes', {}, 'POST', function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            alert('Success!  From FB: ' + e.result);
        } else {
            if (e.error) {
                alert(e.error);
            } else {
                alert('Unkown result');
            }
        }
    });
```

i have generated an url for the page to be liked from [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) but i don't think this is the required 'OBJECT_ID' for that graph request.
What is the OBJECT_ID ?!

Comment: you can't do likes to pages from graph api requests

Comment: any other way please ?!

Comment: you can use the default like button

Comment: any example or a tutorial ? please please please :)

Comment: Do you mean the web button generated from the redirection from the facebook url ?

Comment: yap, this web button https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/

Comment: i'll need a webView then ... thanks very much